# Remove default controller to url - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller, default

I would like to know how to remove the default controller from home url on codeigniter.

Here is my htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets/|css|img|js|fonts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And here is my routes file

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/index";
```

Comment: You already removed the default home controller to `pages/index` file whats your problem?

Comment: try add this $route['yourname'] = "pages/index"; and then use a redirect on controller.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is:- http://www.example.com/
Default controller is: - homepage
Want to display the content of 'homepage' controller on 'http://www.example.com/'

So, first create 'homepage' controller as a default controller with following process:-
Reach to the routes.php file through path 'application/config/routes.php', then change '$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";' to '$route['default_controller'] = "homepage";'

And write down the contents which you wants to display on the 'http://www.example.com/', under the 'index' function 'homepage' controller

Comment: I want a url like this :
http://www.example.com
but i have one like this
http://www.example.com/pages